# Preview download size of app on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I do not seem to be able to see how large an app's download size in the play store is prior to buying it or agreeing to install it.

Is there a means of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the application page, press the green dialog, then scroll down to the bottom, and you will find all the infomation there.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Play Store` app on your phone you can find that information by clicking `Read More` option.

And in [webversion](http://play.google.com) you can find the app info that you are downloading by viewing the `Additional Information` section where it has `Size` information at the bottom of that app details part.

Comment: +1, [For reader]: Note that the web version may not show app size for all apps since some app's size varies from device to device.